# Java Isolate comma seperated values in text file

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I've been searching for a solution to my problem without any luck. So now I'm asking here for help.

I'm creating "Groups" by the following class:

```
public class Group {
   private String groupID;
   private ArrayList<User> usersInGroup;
```

The User class looks like this:
NOTE: I already have an ArrayList containing all existing Users.

```
public class User {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String age;
   private String gender;
   private String usernameID;
   private String password;
```

I'm already adding the groupID field from the "groupData.txt" CSV text file like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Group> listOfCreatedGroups() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Group> listOfGroups = new ArrayList<>();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/groupData.txt");
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    int totalLine = Destination.linesInFile("src/groupData.txt"); //total lines in file

    for (int i = 0; i < totalLine; i++) {
        line = bfr.readLine();
        String[] groupID = line.split(",");
        Group temp = new Group();

        temp.setGroupID(groupID[0]);

        listOfGroups.add(temp);
    }
    try {
        bfr.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listOfGroups;
}
```

The "groupData.txt" file is structured like this:

> Line example = *groupID,String_1,String2,String3 ... Stringn,\n*
>
> groupid,user,user,user,user,user,user,user,
>
> groupid,user,user,user,
>
> groupid,user,user,user,user,user
>
> groupid,user,user
>
> groupid,user,user,user,user

Since I only have the number of users in every group *User.usernameID* as 1 to n strings in the text file I can't add the whole User object to the Arraylist usersInGroup.
I somehow need to isolate the usernameID's and find the corresponding Users and add them to the ArrayList usersInGroup.

I hope any of you can give me a hint in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a multiline example of your csv and what the class instances should be

Comment: What is user paste with examples you have a whole user class but no data to go in it

Comment: Yes. A multiline example is added to the post now. The instances are as shown in the post aswell. In the method shown "listOfCreatedGroups()" i want a list of all the created groups. Each group is made from each line in the text file.

Comment: Sorry. I already have an ArrayList containing all the existing Users. Each user is created in a similar fashion - also from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is how you were wanting because I didn't find the user data very specific or even mentioned of how you wanted. But let me know if this is enough

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Group {
        private static String groupID;
        private static ArrayList<User> usersInGroup = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        addListToGroup(readFile());
    }
    public static void addListToGroup(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            groupID = list.get(i).get(0);
            for (int x = 0; x < list.get(i).size(); x++) {
                User temp = new User(); // change this to however you setup the txt file 
                // the information from the list is in list.get(i).get(x) in order as in the textfile
                temp.setAge(null);
                temp.setFirstName(null);
                temp.setGender(null);
                temp.setLastName(null);
                temp.setPassword(null);
                temp.setUsernameID(null);
                usersInGroup.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFile() throws IOException {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
        temp = Files.readAllLines(path);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            String [] s = temp.get(i).split(",");
            ArrayList<String> quickArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int x=0; x < s.length; x++) {
                quickArray.add(s[x]);
            }
            lines.add(quickArray);
        }
        return lines;
    }

}
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;
    private String gender;
    private String usernameID;
    private String password;
    //setters and getters
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getUsernameID() {
        return usernameID;
    }
    public void setUsernameID(String usernameID) {
        this.usernameID = usernameID;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```